# Oracle PL/SQL return from procedure with OUT variables

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to use a PL/SQL procedure with an `OUT` variable as a return code instead of `Raise_Application_Error` and instead of lots of nested if/then?

Example:

```
Create or replace procedure myProc (
  ID in number
  ..
  ,message out varchar2
) as
..
BEGIN
  if not ( myCheck1 ) then
    message := 'Unsuccessful check1';
    return; -- !!! using return here causes message is empty :-( 
  end if;

  some code goes here;

  if not ( myCheck2 ) then
    message := 'Unsuccessful check2';
    return; -- !!! using return here causes message is empty :-( 
  end if;

  not deeply nested code goes here;

END;
```

Of course it is possible to achieve requested output using if / else,
but when using multiple nested checks, the code is hard to read,
because long nested if/else structures, like this example:

```
..
BEGIN
  if not ( myCheck1 ) then
    message := 'Unsuccessful check1';
  else
    ..
    if not ( myCheck2 ) then
      message := 'Unsuccessful check2';
    else
      ..
      ..
      if not ( myCheck3 ) then
        message := 'Unsuccessful check3';
      else
        ..
        deeply nested code goes here; -- :-(
      end if; -- end of check3
    end if; -- ned of check2
  end if; -- end of check1
END;


declare
  message  varchar2(100);
Begin
  myProc (
  '123' -- ID
  ..
  ,message
  );
  dbms_output.put_line( message ); -- any output here when using RETURN statement :-(
END;
/
```

Comment: Please consider the (fairly obvious) fact that not everyone here is a "gent", thanks. We want to be inclusive of everyone here.

Comment: Why do you think you can't use RETURN like that? It's perfectly acceptable, so long as you're in a procedure. If you're in a function, then you will have to return a value or an exception in order to successfully exit the function.

Comment: @Boneist - I would say the syntax allows us to use RETURN like that, but I don't think it's *acceptable* ;)

Comment: @APC yeah, sorry, I meant it was acceptable as in it won't cause the code to error. Whether it's good practice to use it like that is a whole 'nother matter! *{;-)

Comment: Why don't you change your object to a function(instead of procedure) and return the string instead of defining direction to OUT? return is much better as you can call your function in a select.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement your first approach using user-defined exceptions. These allow us to channel bespoke exceptions neatly into the standard exception handling section. This at least makes the code easier to understand. Also, raising exceptions is idiomatic PL/SQL, whereas using `return` in the way you show is exactly the same as using a `goto` statement, only less honest :)

```
Create or replace procedure myProc (
  ID in number
  ..
  ,message out varchar2
) as
..
  x_check_1 exception;
  x_check_2 exception;
BEGIN
  if not ( myCheck1 ) then
    raise x_check_1;
  end if;

  some code goes here;

  if not ( myCheck2 ) then
       raise x_check_2;
  end if;

  not deeply nested code goes here;
EXCEPTION
    when x_check_1 then
        message := 'Unsuccessful check1';
    when x_check_2 then
        message := 'Unsuccessful check2';
END;
```

Generally speaking, using OUT parameters to pass status codes or messages is not good practice: they're too easy to ignore. We can associate user-defined exceptions with numbers in the set-aside range `-20999` to `-20000` . Thus we can raise bespoke exceptions and bubble up responsibility for handling them to  the calling program.

```
Create or replace procedure myProc (
  ID in number
  ..
) as
..
  x_check_1 exception;
  pragma exception_init(x_check_1, -20000);
  x_check_2 exception;
  pragma exception_init(x_check_2, -20001);
BEGIN
  if not ( myCheck1 ) then
    raise x_check_1;
  end if;
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `raise_application_error` but then catch it and converrt into out param.

```
procedure p(param out varchar2)
begin
--logic with raise_application_error and exceptions thrown
exception when others then
param := --what you need to return in out
end;
/
```